# Is the fund received to my indian bank from foreign bank taxable?

Tags: taxes, india, income, nepal

I am Nepali citizen and I have ordinary saving account in Indian bank. I was also working here for 2 years in the past(3 years ago) and I have PAN card and bank account. Now I am living in India for short term (180 days) and I am getting fund in my account for my expenses. Is the income i received from foreign is taxable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the funds are part of salary then it is taxable in India. If the funds are sent by your family for your study etc, then its not taxable.

For more details on taxation of Foreign Nationals refer to http://www.investingintamilnadu.com/india/doc/guide_investors/guide_expats_working_india.pdf